# Problem with electrical switch

Tags: switch

I have a switch that’s supplied with electric but can’t find out what is it for
How can I find out what is that switch for?

Comment: I would get a portable light and start checking receptacles in that room. Many times 1/2 of 1 duplex receptacle is controlled by a switch.

Comment: Check every socket of every receptacle.  One of them will be switched.